# Unknown error in google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I already tried the stackoverflow question related to this, but unable to solve this.
Below is the code of my javascript for google map, i am trying to call google map on changing a dropdown, but in console it is raising "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined" error. Anyone Please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#tohide").hide();
    $('#id_area_name').on('change', function(e) {
        var Value = this.value;
        var formURL = "/users/add_dispensary/" + Value + "/";
        if (Value){
            $.ajax({
                url: formURL,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data){
                    data = data + "<tr><th></th><td><button class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>&nbsp;<button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Cancel</button></td></tr>"
                    $("#dispensaryform").html(data);
                    $("#tohide").show();
                    $("#map").show();
                    $('#dispensaryform tbody td').siblings().css("border-top", 0);
                    $('#dispensaryform tbody th').siblings().css("border-top", 0);
                    $('#dispensaryform tbody td').siblings().addClass("col-lg-4");
                    $('#dispensaryform tbody th').siblings().addClass("col-lg-8");
                    create_map();
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Something wrong happened")
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            data='';
            $("#dispensaryform").html(data);
            $("#tohide").hide();
            $("#map").hide();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
<script>
    function create_map(){
        var Lati = $("#id_Latitude").val();
        var Long = $("#id_Longitude").val();
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lati, Long);
        //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
        var myOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // HYBRID
            disableDefaultUI: true
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this issue by just adding a zoom level like this:-

```
var myOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // HYBRID
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            zoom:11
        };
```